# How can I use PHP to make secure calls to MySQL Databases?

Tags: php, mysql, security, database-connection

I recently started coding another website, the first one in 5 years. Before I was very familiar with using PHP/Javascript to code a website and its layout. Very seldom did I use it for user accounts(if so I had a friend code it), I only used it to store data for products for layout purposes.

At the moment, I will not be using SSL until I purchase a certificate.

So now i will use PHP to keep names, emails, addresses, phone numbers, etc. all stored on a database. I looked through hundreds of documentation and found nothing that is easy for me to understand since I barely remember anything but simple coding.

I did find a few step by step tutorials on making SQL injections and such but they date back to 2005. I'm looking for something much more recent.

Ideally, all I'm looking for is a great place to start (without starting a beginner php) to making a website secure with php when usling MySQL. For instance, password encryptions and such; along with calling and injecting to the database.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Thank you guys, I've been busy with work and I waited for an answer that will suffice.  I didn't get quite what I asked for; probably my fault, however. I looked at proper documentation, but always just throw operators and little functions just like javascript in my face. I'm past that, I want unique functions that have a purpose and I'm unaware where to get those. they seem to be way too complex for me or just far too simple.

I thought about using openSSL but if I do recall I need to install it, that won't happen for the cheap hosting my client pays for. I told my client I was only familiar with this stuff and its best to go else where other than design, he didn't care how long it took. so now I have to learn this all over again quickly.

Comment: I suggest you ask over on [webmasters.se] instead.  SO is more for programming questions involving actual code.  Please read the [faq] and [ask] for more information.

Comment: @Jim: I think this would be more appropriate here, since the answers *would* involve code.

Comment: @icktoofay I guess I can see it either way, which is which I didn't downvote or closevote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Secure backend connections**:
    If you want to secure the connection from a web server to the database server, you could use [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) to generate an SSL certificate and set up secure connections with the [`MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL` flag in `mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) like in [this article](http://www.madirish.net/node/244)
2. **Sanitize input**:
    To prevent SQL injections, make sure that the input you use in queries, is actually the input you would expect, either through [input validation based on input types](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Validating-User-Input.html), or by escaping metacharacters, like with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
3. **Password Hashing**:
    Something as simple as one-way hashing, for example with [`SHA-1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php), can help you store user passwords in a more safe manner. Store password hashes, and then compare the stored hash with a hash of the password input during authentication.

Comment: About `mysql_real_escape_string()`. The easiest solution (for me at least) in the long run is to use PDO or similar to create prepared statements instead of relying on escape methods. Any decent library should take care of that part by itself, and you don't have to remember manually escaping and adding quotes if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statements will pretty much completely protect you from SQL injection.

However I find they're a pain in the rear end to implement when all you really have to do is put the input through `mysql_real_escape_string` and make sure it's in quotes in the query so the would-be-hacker can't break out of the string.

Comment: Or MySQLi, that also uses prepared statements

Comment: @Kolink I used to think so too, but once I got used to prepared statements I think they are easier to handle. Escaping variables clutters the code and you have to be careful so that you remember everyone. Another disadvantage is that it "ruins" the variables if you have to use them later in the function, so you end up with a special escaped duplicate of the variable to keep them separate. `$statement->execute($query,array($name,$user,$email))` is a nice and compact way of doing this.